# Best place to put SQL statements in Java

Tags: java, sql, spring, architecture

I know there are pros and cons to each approach, but is there a best practice on where to put the SQL statements?  I've always put them inside of the Java classes, but I came on to a project where they are injected via Spring string constructors.  The reason is that if the SQL statements are in an application context, you don't have to remove all of the " and + to get the SQL to copy/paste on the server.  I don't think that's a good reason, but that's what I stepped in to for the moment.
I know this can also be done with properties.

So my question is should the SQL statements go in the application context, Java file, properties file, or some place I'm not thinking of?

---

Update:

From the replies I got, it seems that prepared statements are the best place for SQL statements.  But what about SQL statements that are generated on the fly dynamically?  The code will have many different strings that will all be concatenated together to make a query depending on what is passed in.  If we have a method with 6 input parameters that could be passed in (or not), I would need an incredible amount of prepared statements to account for all the possibilities.

I've considered using an ORM tool such as Hibernate, but I'm working with an iSeries database and the tables are not well constructed.  Perhaps someday I can rewrite Hibernate in and write out the 900 line SQL statements... but one step at a time.

Comment: In stored procedures.

Comment: Well, first of all, you should always use precompiled statements (PreparedStatements). This way, all your queries can normally be fixed Strings with parameters. If you inject them or not, probably you will have to change code if you modify the query, so I would rather ask you what the needs (non-functional requierements) of your particular case are, this way it would be easier to give you some objective answer.

Comment: SQL in databases doesn't get versioned in Git. That's a deal breaker. Yes you can and should at least attempt to version your database schema and so on but the tools for doing so are lacking. Not to mention most of the time it's extra steps to make modifications; DBAs and extra red tape involved. The whole idea of putting business logic in your database instead of a service layer was largely rejected by many devs years ago. Solutions like PL/SQL promote vendor lock-in. Only as a last resort when it's truly needed for performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no rule about where is the best place : it's somehow like "where's the best place to put my keys at home".

If your project needs require you to have the SQL accessible from outside the app, then why not putting them in properties files. In that case, you may want to check that changes in the Sql are still compatible with your app by doing some JUnit tests.

Stored procedures are good because of their execution speed, but bad because they split your app configuration in two places. In addition they are tightly coupled with the database software (which again depending on the project can be a good or bad thing)

Hope my answer helped you asking your self the right questions in your own context.

Best Regards,
Zied

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Thiharas answer, but why not go one step further and save them in .sql files within the application. With each query having its own file it becomes easier to manage.

That is of course if an ORM framework like Hibernate will not be suitable for your application.

Comment: My problem is that I have so many different combinations of SQL that could be built it would be difficult to put them all in stored procedures.  The SQL is generated via Java String concatenation when the method is called.  Hibernate would be perfect for this... but it's a legacy system (iSeries database).  Maybe one day, but I need to go one step at a time.

Comment: Can you use SQL files with prepared statements?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the only reason. When the SQL statements are out side of the Java code you can change it without having to re compile and deploy your application. If the queries are periodically loaded from the files (say once every 8 hours) then you don't even have to do a server restart. That will be very beneficial for the people doing production application support.

Also regarding the first reason you don't consider a good reason; when you have to debug a big assed SQL statement and need to paste it in a query executor removing all `+` and '"' signs I'm sure you will change your mind :-)

Comment: I've had to debug huge SQL statements with the + and " and yes, they are a pain.  I just set up some JUnit tests that allow me to pull the SQL from the variables via debugging, so hopefully those days are gone regardless of where the SQL is.